# How important it is to get website to also work with Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have been using HTML, CSS, JS and jQuery in my web development and it is my first time. I have been testing my design on Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge, and it works perfectly.

But when it comes to Internet Explorer, things just don't work well. Squeezed images, animation not working, margin/padding issues, flickering image when scrolling etc...

So my question is, are there any merits in getting any websites to work flawlessly with IE? IE is like the least popular browser now that Microsoft Edge is here (from what I read sometime ago). Just wondering if I should invest my time in getting my website to work with Internet Explorer.

Comment: Depends on your users or how important it is to your boss. If you are just doing this as a hobby, I highly suggest to ignore any version of IE.

Comment: I've heard of firms that have some weird internal systems that only work on IE, but for general purposes, no just ignore IE.

Answer (score -1):

@zaraku27

I think you should make a website which is compatible on every browser although Internet Explorer is not commonly used by everyone because of some other modern browsers but some of the application are optimized only for IE and some websites can only be used on IE whereas it is faster with windows computer because it is integrated. It is also simpler to use then other modern browser like Chrome, FireFox, Opera and etc and it is highly compatible with almost all the Operating System.

The versions 9 and above of Internet Explorer use HTML5 which enhances browsing experience, This lets the user to stream videos and audios excluding any type requirements of installing additional plugins IE being one of the oldest and conventional web browsers support many of the applications which some modern web browsers may not support .

Comment: "it is highly compatible with almost all the Operating System" — Rubbish. It won't run on anything other than Windows.

Comment: "The versions 9 and above of Internet Explorer use HTML5" — Internet Explorer has the worst support for HTML 5 among all commonly used browsers.

Comment: "it is faster with windows computer because it is integrated " — [The first performance comparison I found](https://blogs.systweak.com/2017/11/which-is-faster-ie-11-vs-firefox-vs-google-chrome-vs-opera/) claims Firefox was faster than IE in tests.